# How to flatten nested list keeping inner structure

Tags: r, list, dplyr

Let's say I have the following list (`result`), which is a nested list that captures information from a model: parameters (`betas`) and their standard errors (`sd`), additionally with some information regarding the global model (`method`) and the number of observations (`n`).

I want to flatten the lists `betas` and `sd` while distinguishing where each value of `x1` and `x2` comes from (i.e. if they are from `betas` or `sd`).

Please gently consider the following example:

```
result<- list(n       = 100,
              method  = "tree", 
              betas   = list(x1 = 1.47,
                             x2 = -2.85),
              sd      = list(x1 = 0.55,
                             x2 = 0.25))

str(result)
# List of 4
# $ n         : num 100
# $ iterations: num 50
# $ betas     :List of 2
# ..$ x1: num 1.47
# ..$ x2: num -2.85
# $ sd        :List of 2
# ..$ x1: num 0.55
# ..$ x2: num 0.25
```

#### First attempt: `flatten()`. [Spoiler(!): I lose the precedence of each value]

```
## I can't distinguish between betas and sd.
flatten(result)

# $n
# [1] 100
# 
# $iterations
# [1] 50
# 
# $x1
# [1] 1.47
# 
# $x2
# [1] -2.85
# 
# $x1
# [1] 0.55
#
# $x2
# [1] 0.25
```

#### Second attempt: `unlist()`. [Spoiler(!), I need a list, not an atomic vector]

```
#I need a list 
unlist(result)

# n iterations   betas.x1   betas.x2      sd.x1      sd.x2 
# 100.00      50.00       1.47      -2.85       0.55       0.25
```

#### Desired Output.

```
list(n        = 100,
    method   = "tree", 
    betas.x1 = 1.47,
    betas.x2 = -2.85,
    sd.x1    = 0.55,
    sd.x2    = 0.25)

# List of 6
# $ n       : num 100
# $ method  : chr "tree"
# $ betas.x1: num 1.47
# $ betas.x2: num -2.85
# $ sd.x1   : num 0.55
# $ sd.x2   : num 0.25
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as.data.frame` will flatten for you. From `?as.data.frame`:

> *Arrays with more than two dimensions are converted to matrices by
> 'flattening' all dimensions after the first and creating suitable
> column labels.*

Which does a poor job of explaining that it operates on nested lists as well, not just arrays. (In other words, I think the docs do not discuss this feature on non-arrays.)

```r
str(as.data.frame(result))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ n       : num 100
#  $ method  : chr "tree"
#  $ betas.x1: num 1.47
#  $ betas.x2: num -2.85
#  $ sd.x1   : num 0.55
#  $ sd.x2   : num 0.25
```

If you don't want/need a `list`, just `as.list` it next:

```r
str(as.list(as.data.frame(result)))
# List of 6
#  $ n       : num 100
#  $ method  : chr "tree"
#  $ betas.x1: num 1.47
#  $ betas.x2: num -2.85
#  $ sd.x1   : num 0.55
#  $ sd.x2   : num 0.25
```

Comment: Thanks for this; it solved my problem. Additionally, a couple of minutes after posting the question, I used `as.list(unlist(result, recursive = FALSE,use.names = T))`, which produces the same desired output. Do you have any comments about why preferring one approach on top of the other? Thx again.

Comment: Nope. In fact, your code is significantly faster than `as.data.frame` (which includes lots of checks and such). If it works, use your code :-)